# Parse JSON values stored in LocalStorage using JSP?

Tags: json, jsp, local-storage

I know how to parse JSON using JS but can't use that variable in JSP. Is there any workaround in JSP like built in method in JS? What i'll do next is store that JSP myData variable in the database.

```
String myData[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
```

Comment: Well, the key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response. And as LocalStorage is browser-side thing, you simply cannot access it from JSP.

Comment: Thank you sir. my bad i wrote a client side script rather than server side one, should have used sessions here. i need to rewrite my code. thought that there is a workaround here. btw thank you for your answer.